What integration techniques can I use to integrate such a long function?
I'm still new to integration (and math, generally) and I'm facing the following problem with a function that my math professor has thrown away at me to solve, I can't even comprehend how can I use a certain method to solve this, I tried substituting a couple of times but I can't get what's my mistake
$$\dfrac{\left(\left(x-2\right)\mathrm{e}^x-x\right)\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{\mathrm{e}^x+x}}{2x}\right)}{4x^2\sqrt{\mathrm{e}^x+x}}$$

hint: what is the derivative of $\frac{\sqrt{e^x+x}}{2x}$ ?

You'll straightforwardly substitute $u = \frac{\sqrt{e^x+x}}{2x}$ try to do the rest on your own to get to the point where your integral is equal to $\sin(u)$, then you'll undo the substitution to have your final answer as:
$$\sin(\dfrac{\sqrt{e^x+x}}{2x})+C$$

$$\int \dfrac{\left(\left(x-2\right)\mathrm{e}^x-x\right)\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{\mathrm{e}^x+x}}{2x}\right)}{4x^2\sqrt{\mathrm{e}^x+x}}dx$$
Firstly We can take out the constant
$$I= \frac{1}{4}\int \dfrac{\left(\left(x-2\right)\mathrm{e}^x-x\right)\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{\mathrm{e}^x+x}}{2x}\right)}{x^2\sqrt{\mathrm{e}^x+x}}dx$$
Then we can substitute $u=\frac{\sqrt{x+e^x}}{2x}$ and $du=(\frac{e^x+1}{4x\sqrt{x+e^x}}-\frac{\sqrt{x+e^x}}{2x^2})$
$$I= \int \cos(u) du$$
The integral of $\cos(u)$ is $
\sin(u)+C$
Finally we substitute back $u=\frac{\sqrt{x+e^x}}{2x}$
$$I=\sin(\frac{\sqrt{x+e^x}}{2x})+C$$
